# What is the reason that some departments do not allow PhD students to be instructors of record?

Tags: phd, teaching

It is common that PhD students have teaching duties as TA. In this case, the person ultimately for the course (the **instructor of record**) is a faculty member. I should note that I am talking only about enrolled PhD students at the same university as where the undergraduate course is taught.

In some places, it seems that PhD students can serve as the instructor of record, but at many other places they are not.

What are the reasons why PhD students are not permitted to be  instructors of record at some universities in the USA and Europe?

Comment: In Italy a PhD student can't officially have the responsibility of a course, and there are also limitations (which depend on the university) on the number of teaching hours he or she can do as a TA.

Comment: In the Netherlands, this is actually pretty common. One of the reasons is that here, PhD candidates are not considered students, but employees (that's changing right now, and a big issue).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answers to your question depends on the country and/or department in which a PhD student is studying.

Comment: It is different in different systems as is evident from the comments. In Sweden, a student could not be officially responsible but could of course still do most of the work. This comes from the fact that the university system is run by the government and examination is an official task which requires a certain position. Someone other than the student will have to stand officially responsible for the course in the end.

Comment: I agree with the close vote. *Of course* it is possible in some places, including, for instance, Austria. I am not sure what productive conclusions one could take from this information, though.

Comment: I reworded it to try to get closer to the intent of the OP and to make it less braod.

Comment: @RoboKaren I don't necessarily think the OP's intent was to ask for reasons - I think the OP wanted to poll the community to find out how common this is (which is not what this site is for, per the [help/dont-ask]). However, the old question didn't seem salvageable and the new one is reasonable, so even though I don't think it's what the OP intended, I reopened it.

Comment: Are there ranking systems which take into account "percent of classes taught by faculty with terminal degrees"? I kind of thought this was a thing, which would suggest one reason why some universities might not allow graduate students to be instructors of record, but it looks like US News at least does not consider this.

Comment: @NateEldredge US News does count "Percent faculty with terminal degree in their field" and also "Percent faculty that is full time" (see their [ranking criteria and weights](http://www.usnews.com/education/best-colleges/articles/2014/09/08/best-colleges-ranking-criteria-and-weights)). That is indeed a reason why some departments try to avoid grad student instructors.

Comment: @ff254: I see, and a grad student teaching their own class would presumably be counted as "faculty" for that term. Makes sense.

Comment: In Australia, PhD students are sessional teachers, and in some cases, do have full responsibility for a unit. They are not considered faculty and would probably be akin to Adjunct professors in the US system as it is a per course/subject. I was a sessional lecturer/Chief examiner for a unit two years running, and then was offered a one year contract as a full-time faculty member. Despite running the units, as a sessional I was not considered faculty.

Comment: The most probable reason is that as a PhD student, you are not employed to have the responsibility of a course. It's also a way to protect PhD students from being held responsible for things that they are not supposed to handle.

Comment: At my university, you need a PhD to be able to assign a grade. A student can grade assignments in pass/fail  (or actually, pass/repeat).

Comment: I'll give you a small historic flashback. Back in the 1910s and 1920s, women were already allowed to study, but mostly were not yet allowed to teach. So when [Emmy Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether) wanted to do some teaching, her supervisor, [David Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hilbert) had to be the instructor on the record™ for some of her lectures, until the faculty finally caved in and gave her a somewhat reasonable position (but not really equal and appropriate to what she would have got if she were male). So, you at least seem to be in a good company.

Comment: Corrected "on record" to "of record."  Feel free to revert if this wasn't just a typo.

Answer (score 9):

My institution (which is a highly ranked R1 private university) tries to differentiate itself from other universities by advertising that all of our professors teach  and that the undergraduates -- if they choose to come here -- will learn directly at the feet of the greatest scholars in the world (blah blah blah..).

My cynical quip aside, we try very hard at least nominally to ensure this. All professors in the arts and sciences teach their own classes (research staff at the medical school are of course exempt), although some teach less than others.

Very few graduate students are permitted to be instructors of record -- only just a handful of 6th and 7th years are given this right, and only in very focused seminars.

For us, it's a bit of a matter of pride -- what differentiates us from some of the other R1s. But like most things in the neoliberal academy, there has been talk of bringing in adjunct faculty and other changes that will certainly dilute the claim made in the opening paragraph above.

Comment: My graduate institution, another highly ranked R1 private university (we may both be selling our schools short here), also advertises the fact that no courses are taught by graduate students. Yet according to my CV, I was instructor of record for 6 courses while I was a Ph.D. student there. How can this be? Well, they made sure to give all the grad students a Master's before we started teaching, so they can argue that we were hired as Lecturers -- and if we **happened** to be in the Ph.D. program at the same time, what a coincidence!

Comment: The "masters" trick is also important for other things, like the percentage of classes taught by someone with a higher degree which some accreditation agencies care about.  (Though I think it doesn't work for gaming US News, who counts only people with the highest degree in their field.)

Answer (score 0):

This will obviously vary among countries, institutions and also departments.

At my department (a Norwegian University (magic fairyland where "PhD student" is a regular, well-paid job), CS dept.) I did my first lecturing as a PhD student (a Master-level, seminar-style course) and was also the official "instructor" (together with another PhD student). The year after, while still working on my PhD, I was employed to teach a major undergrad course, also as the official (and solely responsible) instructor; I had no supervision or follow-up: no one pre-approved my lession plan, checked on my lectures, looked at the exercises I made or even checked the exam and the grading. Fortunately, it went well, and I was given the course again the next years (as a post doc), and I'm still teaching it now (as associate professor).

On the other hand, at our neighbouring department, they don't even let PhD students and post docs be officially responsible for small stuff like supervising bachelor students.

In general, good teaching requires both skill, knowledge and motivation. If you're lucky, your personality and previous experiences will be enough to do good or even great teaching, even if you're an inexperienced PhD student (or perhaps not even that – I've had 2nd year Bachelor students deliver awesome lectures!). It's quite a gamble, though, and an inexperienced lecturer can just as easily be a disaster (then again, the same goes for an unmotivated experienced one).

So, it makes sense to provide fresh lecturers (whether they're PhD students or newly hired staff) with guidance and supervision until both they and the department are comfortable with them taking full responsibility. Educating and training people is part of a University's mission, and that also applies to training lecturers – a department shouldn't just pick random PhD students to lecture courses and hope they eventually hit on a rare, talented "great teacher".

So who should be the "instructor on record"? The person(s) who's actually responsible for the teaching, no matter the title. Having a rule that says "a PhD student can't be ultimately responsible for a course" is probably meant to avoid having courses taught by underqualified lecturers and sort of makes sense from a bureaucratic perspective (could even be that my own University has more-or-less this rule). Doesn't really help, though, if the department appoints a nominal "official instructor" and gives the actual job to a PhD student anyway.